# descending loop with variable bash

Tags: bash

```
$ cat fromhere.sh
#!/bin/bash

FROMHERE=10

for i in $(seq $FROMHERE 1)
do
echo $i
done
$ sh fromhere.sh
$
```

Why doesn't it works?
I can't find any examples searching google for a descending loop..., not even variable in it. Why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should specify the increment with seq:

```
seq $FROMHERE -1 1
```

Answer (score 19):

Bash has a `for` loop syntax for this purpose. It's not necessary to use the external `seq` utility.

```
#!/bin/bash

FROMHERE=10

for ((i=FROMHERE; i>=1; i--))
do
    echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 4):

You might prefer Bash *builtin* Shell Arithmetic instead of spawning external *seq*:

```
i=10
while (( i >= 1 )); do
    echo $(( i-- ))
done
```

Comment: @marco: But in Bash, you can't use variables inside brace range expressions.

Answer (score 4):

loop down with for (stop play)

```
for ((q=500;q>0;q--));do echo $q ---\>\ `date +%H:%M:%S`;sleep 1;done && pkill mplayer
```

```css
500 ---> 18:04:02
499 ---> 18:04:03
498 ---> 18:04:04
497 ---> 18:04:05
496 ---> 18:04:06
495 ---> 18:04:07
...
...
...
5 ---> 18:12:20
4 ---> 18:12:21
3 ---> 18:12:22
2 ---> 18:12:23
1 ---> 18:12:24
```

pattern :

```
for (( ... )); do ... ; done
```

example

```
for ((i=10;i>=0;i--)); do echo $i ; done
```

result

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

with while:
first step

```
AAA=10
```

then

```
while ((AAA>=0));do echo $((AAA--));sleep 1;done
```

or:
"AAA--" into while

```
while (( $((AAA-- >= 0)) ));do echo $AAA;sleep 1;done
```

"sleep 1" isn't need