# how to set variable for bash loop array

Tags: bash, variables, loops

I would like to have a bash loop function like below, with decreasing sequency:

```
for i in {8..2}
do
...
done
```

And the 8 and 2 can be set as a variable, like:

```
start=$1
end=$2

for i in {$start..$end}
do
...
done
```

But seem this dose not work. How can I do this?

Thanks for all the quick answers, later I found the answer here.
[descending loop with variable bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679188/descending-loop-with-variable-bash)

solution:

```
start=$1
end=$2

for i in `seq $start -1 $end`
do
...
done
```

Thanks~

Comment: Thanks, but one difference, I need a decrease seq as {8..2},but not {2..8}, and the `seq $start $end` dose not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ start=8; end=2; for ((i = start; i >= end; i--)); do echo "${i}"; done
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. But here is a workaround

```
start=$1
end=$2

for i in $(seq $start $end)
do
...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variable substitution there since the {n..m} is already one.
Try using `seq`:

```
for i in `seq $start $end`
do
  ...
done
```

Alternatively you could do a while loop incrementing the loop variable by manually:

```
i=$start
while [ $i -lt $end ]; do
  ...
  : $[i++]
done
```

Although with while you have to be aware if `$start` is smaller or greater than `$end`